# How to make a SignalR chat in winforms

Tags: signalr

i´m new doing client-server apps, and i have a problem. I want to create a simple chat in C# with SignalR but I need to do it in a winforms.Net Framework (client) and the Server in a console project. I have searched a lot of information, but all people only do it in an asp.net project. I tried to adapt the code, but i had a lot of problems. I'm a bit lost on this topic ¿Can someone help me , pls? Thanks a lot for ur feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up SignalR as follows in your Startup and Program (c#) classes:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;


namespace SignalServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var url = "http://localhost:8080/";
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Server running at {url}");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR("/signalchat", new HubConfiguration());
        }
    }
}
```

You can find detailed information here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181555/SignalChat-WPF-SignalR-Chat-Application

For console applications, see this GitHub repository: https://github.com/Expecho/Self-Hosted-SignalR